# Compilation error when installing Xen hypervisor

Tags: gcc, xen

When I run the `make world` command I got this error.
Anyone know what is causing this? I think it is related to my gcc version, but I could not upgrade it in debian. My gcc version is 4.7.2

```
numa.c: In function ‘acpi_parse_slit’:
numa.c:99:6: error: variable ‘localities’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-    variable]
numa.c: In function ‘acpi_parse_srat’:
numa.c:152:26: error: variable ‘srat’ set bbut not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-    variable]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by two variables being defined, set to a value, and then never used - the error messages pretty much say that... In addition, you have `-Werror` or one of its variants set, that turns what would normally be just a warning for a useless construct into an error, which causes the build to terminate.

Either remove the definitions of those two variables (probably not the best solution), or fix your build flags to get rid of the `-Werror` bits that escalate warnings into errors...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Because I am new, I do not know how can I fix build flag? could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "KBUILD_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable" to your Makefile(found in Xen root).